# What does `return function *(){...}` mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I saw something strange in [Koa](https://github.com/koajs/koa). It has some new function names (from https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/examples/co.js#L10):

```
app.use(function(){
  return function *(){
    var paths = yield fs.readdir('docs');

    var files = yield paths.map(function(path){
      return fs.readFile('docs/' + path, 'utf8');
    });

    this.type = 'markdown';
    this.body = files.join('');
  }
});
```

What does `return function *()` mean? Can we declare a function with the name of `*` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It means that the function returns an iterator (so it can be repeatedly called with .next() to yield more values.

check out http://wingolog.org/archives/2013/05/08/generators-in-v8 for more info

It's an ES6 construct, so at the moment you see it more in node rather than client side js

Comment: BTW, it's only availaible in unstable node for now (>=0.11) with the flag `--harmony-generators`

Answer (score 17):

Koa makes use of a new JavaScript feature called *generators*, and the `*` is the way to identify a generator in V8.